# Dropdown in sidebar with specific width

Tags: google-apps-script, sidebar

I've got a sidebar that works as supposed except from the width of the dropdown field.
The content/list of the dropdown is fetched from a column in my spreadsheet. I would like it actually show the dropdown arrow.

[image]

My html looks like this:

```
    <select id="contactType">
    <? for (var i in ansatType) { ?>
      <option value="<?=ansatType[i]?>"><?=ansatType[i]?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
```

I've tried to put in cols = "35", width:150px, width:150, width="150", width="150" style="width: 150px" and width=150 and similar different places but it doesn't seem to impact the width as in a text field.

my code to evaluate goes like this:

```
  var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Contact_sletansat');
    

  html.ansatType = getContacts();
  
  html = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Slet kontakt')
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

The getContacts() just makes an array from a column.

Comment: I believe the problem is the length of the strings your trying to display.  If they get too long then the box get's to large.  Maybe you can change the font-size of the select.